# Returning Promises for use in click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm playing around with returning promises from an AJAX method and seeing how I can use them to make my code more easier to read/functional.  My current scenario is to have a function `getBookIds` which issues an AJAX call to a database to return the title of a book based on its ID.  There are five books in the table and an anchor tag whose text property corresponds to each book.  I want some other fancy AJAX method to fire once all anchor tags have been clicked on.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
HTML
<a href="#">1</a> 
<a href="#">3</a> 
<a href="#">4</a> 
<a href="#">5</a> 
<a href="#">7</a>
```

JS

```
 //hacky globals
 var bookArray = [];
 bookArray.length = $('a').length;

 //ajax function
 function getBookIds(data) {
     return $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Service.asmx/GetBookById",
         data: JSON.stringify({
             'titleId': data
         }),
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json"
     });
 }
 //click handler
 $('a').on('click', function () {
     var index = $('a').index($(this));
     var titleId = $(this).text();
     getBookIds(titleId).done(function (results) {
         bookArray[index] = results.d;
         var isEmpty = arrayChecker(bookArray);
         fancyAjax(isEmpty);
     });
 });
 //checks for undefined values in the array
 function arrayChecker(array) {
     var isEmpty = 0;
     $.each(array, function (key, val) {
         if (val === undefined) {
             isEmpty++;
         }
     });
     return (isEmpty > 0);
 }
 //bool comes from arrayChecker if no undefined then go AJAX
 function fancyAjax(bool) {
     if (!bool) {
         alert('alert message for fancy stuff');
     }
 }
```

This is a contrived example, but I'm struggling to see how I could incorporate these promises into my daily work.  Is this just a bad example to leverage the power of promises/deferreds in the first place?  It seems that instead of the `success` callback on AJAX, not I've got all my logic rolled up inside `done`.  Any suggestions on tackling this better?

Comment: Great question but it belongs in: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JohnStrickler not every question with code belongs in codereview. He is asking about a concept and the code is an example not production code. This question is on topic here and it's not even a bad one :)

Comment: @JohnStrickler I post there as well, I'm happy to have it migrated to where it's most appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want some other fancy AJAX method to fire once all anchor tags have been clicked on.

That sounds like you want to get a promise for each click, which you can then combine into a promise for all clicks. The point is not to use a global `booksArray`, but an array of promises.

```
function getBookIds(data) { … } //ajax function as before

var promises = $('a').map(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        click = $.Deferred();
    $this.one('click', function() { // click handler
        click.resolve($this.text());
    });

    return click.then(getBookIds); // returns a promise for the ajax result
                                   // after the link has been clicked
}).toArray();

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function fancyAjax() {
     alert('alert message for fancy stuff');
});
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7qh7/1/))

Comment: Worth mentioning - the aggregation of a promise array is done with `$.when` in jQuery and with `Promise.all` in more serious promise libraries like Bluebird.

Comment: @Bergi If I were to make this as flexible as possible I would need a function that takes in a jQuery array (in this class anchor tags) and creates a promise for each one, and then check each index's state to see if they are resolved?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: Yes (as the `map` does in my example code) and No, you don't need to check promise states manually. As Benjamin mentioned, you can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to aggregate them.

Comment: @Bergi what's the purpose of `$this.one` and not `on`?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) executes the handler only once, i.e. it unbinds it automatically when not being needed any more (when the promise is already fulfilled)

Comment: @Bergi sounds like the pro way to it. Thanks.  I don't fully grok all your code, but it helps :)

Comment: I learned from this answer, but I think it has a flaw. The `alert('alert message for fancy stuff')` executes before the ajax calls have all returned. That's because the Deferreds are resolved when the ajax calls are made, not when they return. Instead of calling `.then()` on the Deferreds and resolving them in the on-click handler, the ajax calls could be made in the on-click handler. The Deferreds could then be resolved in a `.done()` call placed on the JqXhr objects returned by the ajax calls. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7qh7/).

Comment: @JohnS: Nope, there's no flaw. Not the `click` deferreds which are resolved on-click are returned, but the promises that are built by `then` - which is *chaining* the ajax function into the resolution. Those resulting promises resolve together with the ajax response. Thanks for the fiddle, I've updated it with my code and included some logging: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7qh7/1/!

Comment: Thanks Bergi - I get it now. Here's my original [flawed jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCZ2j/) that made me think there was a flaw in your code. I had moved the call to `.then()` to make it more readable for me, not realizing I was changing the logic. I had mistakenly thought `.then()` returned the original Deferred object, not a new Promise.